# facebook app builder

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am trying to program a facebook app builder that let user to build their app when i try to register a new facebook app using link

https://www.facebook.com/connect/create_app.php?api_key=139080219523603&name=test_create_app&CanvasUtil=http://www.3barat.net/face/index.php?id=25&next=http://apps.facebook.com/today-advice-arabic/new_create.php

i get a message to allow app to create app on behalf user after that it transfer user to  the next page which i define in link the problem is i get a url like that

http://apps.facebook.com/today-advice-arabic/new_create.php#%7B%22new_app_id%22%3A278770428839274%2C%22new_api_key%22%3A%22f12d355261778fd930455cb370b0fb84%22%7D

and i need a way to read response in url that i get, i mean the code after # 
any one can help me

Comment: Does the hash get passed down to your canvas page? If yes: have you tried just parsing location.hash for this data in Javascript? If no: What about using a proxy-script? Set "http://your-domain.com/somescript.htm" as next-param, parse the hash & redirect to a proper Url where you pass the parsed hash as query params. The data is passed in the hash, so I doubt there could be a solution without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I am trying to understand what you are trying to do...

Do you mean you want to create an application that creates applications? Thats not possible.

However - related to your question how to get the data passed to your app:
Its not possible with an hashtag, but just append your data as GET parameter named "app_data" to your URL, like so:

http://apps.facebook.com/today-advice-arabic/new_create.php?app_data=%7B%22new_app_id%22%3A278770428839274%2C%22new_api_key%22%3A%22f12d355261778fd930455cb370b0fb84%22%7D

The data now gets passed to your app inside the Signed Request.

Comment: Isn't app_data only important for page tabs..? Canvas apps get passed all GET params anyhow - or do I confuse something here?

Comment: Nope, you are right - just figured it out by myself - I didn't know that all GET parameters get passed to canvas apps =/